# Why the plotting is not complete?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

The plotting of the path `$x=t,y=\sqrt(1-t^2)$`, by using the code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.4}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
 \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        [xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,axis lines=middle, xtick={2},ytick={2},no marks,axis equal,xmin=-1.4,xmax=1.2,ymax=1.2,ymin=-0.2,enlargelimits={upper=0.1}]
             \addplot[no markers,samples=200, domain=-1:1,variable=t]({t},{pow(1-t^2,1/2)});
        \end{axis}
             \draw (5.8,1.2) node {$1$};
             \draw (3.1,1.2) node {$O$};
             \draw (0.93,1.2) node {$-1$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

is:
[image]

But, in a neighborhood of 1 it seems the graph is not complete. And I don't understand why ?[image]

Later edit: It seems that the circle is no tsmooth aroun 1 and -1, and I don't know where do I wrong ?
[image]

Comment: Off-topic: A `figure` environment is pointless with the `standalone` class. Remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when it divides the interval, it doesn't divide the points appropriately. Instead of writing an even number of samples, write an odd number of samples to fix it.

Instead of `samples = 200`, write `samples = 201`.

```
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
 \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        [xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,axis lines=middle, xtick={2},ytick={2},no marks,axis equal,xmin=-1.4,xmax=1.2,ymax=1.2,ymin=-0.2,enlargelimits={upper=0.1}]
             \addplot[no markers,samples=201, domain=-1:1,variable=t]({t},{pow(1-t^2,1/2)});
        \end{axis}
             \draw (5.8,1.2) node {$1$};
             \draw (3.1,1.2) node {$O$};
             \draw (0.93,1.2) node {$-1$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: With an odd number of samples]

Comment: Thank you very much ! I didn't know that.

Comment: No problem. It took me some time to figure that out when I was learning TikZ. If you accept the answer, don't forget to click the tick mark ;)

Comment: But something is weird. It seems that the line circle is not smooth around 1 (see the image in my later edit). Why ?

Comment: I mean, you are drawing a square root. Given the inherent imprecision of TikZ. And how a square root behaves, you will have a lot of points around the top part, but not a lot of points around the pole at 1 and -1. Try switching to `({sin(t)},{cos(t)})` with  `domain=-90:90` to get a "smooth everywhere" plot

Comment: Ok, thank you ! It's working very well now.